# Install New Module Link Not There

Tags: installation

I've seen this question posted elsewhere here but I haven't seen an answer for it. I am new to Drupal and I'm interested in installing some modules via the Drupal interface, but I don't see the "Install New Module" link on the modules page. (Yes, update manager is already enabled, and going to admin/modules/install doesn't get me anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 components to the *Install New Module* UI access callback:

- It requires the *Administer software updates* permission for the user to be enabled. It can be enabled for any user role underneath the **People > Roles** administration section for the relevant user role.
- It requires `update_manager_access` variable to be set to TRUE. By default, this should be `TRUE`, but it can be overridden in **settings.php** or manually set (e.g. `drush vset update_manager_access 0`). In which case, it needs to be adjusted in settings.php or by updating the variable in the database (`drush vset update_manager_access 1`).

Comment: Hmm, I checked all the roles and permissions, and I do have permission "Administer software updates," but it's still not showing up....

Comment: Check the `update_manager_access` var per updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If every thing is fine @Lisa and still you didn't find "Install new module" under Modules than may be there is a problem with the installation of your drupal version. May be its not installed properly.